# Clickwrap not loading in Browsers other than Microsoft Edge

Tags: docusignapi

I cannot get the Clickwrap examples to load correctly in my browser if I am using Google Chrome or Firefox.  It does work in Microsoft Edge, but not the others.

We created a clickwrap and clicked on “Get Code” for the javascript snipplet (see attachment below), but it seems to only load in Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1038.0.  On Firefox 69.0.3, I get the error “

```
SyntaxError: An invalid or illegal string was specified” on docusign-click.js:1.
```

On Chrome 77.0.3865.90, I get the error

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided ('file://') does not match the recipient window's origin ('null').
```

Do you know how we could fix these problems?  Thank you for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Our engineering team are having trouble reproducing this issue.

If you still have problems - can you contact me so I can put you in touch with our engineering team and try to figure this out.

Alternatively, please make sure you use a clean browser cache, and if you can still reproduce this - please provide all the information about browser versions and what you are doing exactly and/or console output.